# Constrained Maximization (optimization) in R

Tags: r, optimization

I have a simple linear regression model like this:

```
Income=beta_0 + beta_1*YearsCollegeEducation + beta_2*Age
```

Where I have obtained the coefficients:

```
i) beta_0 = 0.8
ii) beta_1=1.9
iii) beta_2=0.5
```

Now I was told to conduct a constrained optimization like this:

```
Max (Income - YearsCollegeEducation*3.4)
such that 35 => Age => 30
```

The second term reflects loan repayment amount for college education

Here is a sample data I created in R:

```
YearsCollegeEducation = c(5,8,4,3,1,2,5,9,4,5)
age = c(24,30,33,22,29,37,29,30,24,31)
data=data.frame(YearsCollegeEducation,Age)
data$intercept = 1
data$Income = data$intercept*0.8+data$YearsCollegeEducations*1.9+data$Age*0.5
```

How should I proceed in R?

Please let me know if I was not clear in any part. I am very new to optimization and have been stuck with this for a while. Thanks.

Comment: do you mind explaining how you obtained your beta estimates as well as how it relates to a constrained maximisation?

Comment: @Trusky I get the beta coefficients using Linear regression. In the example, I simulated data$Income using the relationship. For the second part of the analysis, I was asked to optimize the Function(Income - Total Loan Repayment Amount) subject to the constraint that 35 =>Age =>30. This would be similar to Max Utility type problem in Economics. Please let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: I don't see that any optimization is needed since there i no non-linearity present. You could just evaluate the objective function at either end of that range and decide which one is larger.

Comment: @42- I see what you are saying here. Makes sense. Thank you so much. Would you mind posting this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that any optimization is needed since there is no non-linearity present. You could just evaluate the objective function at either end of that range and decide which one is larger.

```
 objtive <- function( YearsCollegeEducation, Age){ 
     beta_0 = 0.8
     beta_1=1.9
     beta_2=0.5
     Income=beta_0 + beta_1*YearsCollegeEducation + beta_2*Age
     res=Income - YearsCollegeEducation*3.4}
```